# Triviality of a rank-2 Lorentzian vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-bundles, general-relativity

Let $E\to\Sigma$ be a real rank-two vector bundle with a Lorentzian bundle metric. I've heard that such a bundle must necessarily be trivial. This seems surprising since the same is not true with a positive-definite bundle metric. (Consider the tangent bundle of any two-dimensional surface for which there doesn't exist a global nonvanishing vector field.) Why is it the case? Is it possible to directly construct a nonvanishing section?

(In particular, this implies that there exists a nonvanishing null normal vector field along any spacelike embedded codimension-2 submanifold of a Lorentzian manifold.)

Comment: Whom did you hear this from? It is quite false.

Comment: What if one adds the condition that the bundle is orientable?

Comment: Or, if necessary, that $\Sigma$ is two-dimensional, or as a final resort, a two-dimensional sphere? This seems to be commonly used in the general relativity literature, as per the second paragraph of my post.

Comment: Is it your belief that a vector bundle is trivial if and only if it has a (global) nonvanishing section?

Comment: In the case of an orientable rank-two bundle, yes. Is this incorrect?

Comment: For proof, consider an arbitrary positive-definite bundle metric, and given a nonvanishing section, define a second nonvanishing section so that, point by point, they form an oriented orthogonal basis of the fiber. The pair of sections gives a trivialization, no?

Comment: Your claim is true is $\Sigma$ is an orientable surface and the bundle is also orientable. I suppose, these were implicit assumptions in the physics papers you are referring two (for completeness, you should add references).

Answer (score 5):

This is not true.  For instance, given any pair of line bundles $L_+$ and $L_-$, the bundle $L_+\oplus L_-$ has a Lorentzian metric by just taking the direct sum of a positive definite metric on $L_+$ and a negative definite metric on $L_-$.  It's certainly not true that a sum of line bundles is always trivial; in particular, $w_2(L_+\oplus L_-)=w_1(L_+)w_1(L_-)$ and $w_1(L_+\oplus L_-)=w_1(L_+)+w_1(L_-)$ and if either of these are nonzero then $L_+\oplus L_-$ is nontrivial (and $w_1(L_+)$ and $w_1(L_-)$ can be any classes at all in $H^1(\Sigma;\mathbb{Z}/(2))$).  In particular, $L_+\oplus L_-$ can be nontrivial even if it is orientable: orientability means that $w_1=0$, so $w_1(L_+)$ and $w_1(L_-)$ must be the same, but then $w_2$ could still be nontrivial if the class $w_1(L_+)$ has nonzero square.

It is true if $H^1(\Sigma;\mathbb{Z}/(2))$ is trivial, and so in particular if $\Sigma$ is simply connected.  Indeed, Lorentzian plane bundles have structure group $O(1,1)$ which deformation-retracts onto $O(1)\times O(1)\cong \mathbb{Z}/(2)\times\mathbb{Z}/2$.  So, a Lorentzian plane bundle on $\Sigma$ is classified by an element of $H^1(\Sigma;\mathbb{Z}/(2)\times\mathbb{Z}/(2))\cong H^1(\Sigma;\mathbb{Z}/(2))\oplus H^1(\Sigma;\mathbb{Z}/(2))$, and thus is always trivial if $H^1(\Sigma;\mathbb{Z}/(2))$ is trivial.

(In more concrete terms, this is saying every example is of the form in the first paragraph: a Lorentzian plane bundle can always be split up as $L_+\oplus L_-$ where the metric is positive definite on $L_+$ and negative definite on $L_-$.  If $H^1(\Sigma;\mathbb{Z}/(2))$ is trivial, then every line bundle on $\Sigma$ is trivial, and thus $L_+\oplus L_-$ is trivial.)

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you! Could you explain what happens if $E\to M$ is oriented, so that the structure group is $SO(1,1)$ or $SO^+(1,1)$? I'm not so familiar with cohomology so it's not easy for me to say.

Comment: The group $SO^+(1,1)$ is contractible, so every bundle with that structure group is trivial.  The group $SO(1,1)$ has the homotopy type of $O(1)$, so a bundle with $SO(1,1)$ is equivalent to a line bundle.  Another way to think about this is that $L_+\oplus L_-$ is orientable iff $L_+\cong L_-$, so you have just the choice of a single line bundle when constructing such a plane bundle.

Comment: One thing to beware of here is that there are two different notions of isomorphism--being isomorphic as Lorentzian plane bundles is strictly stronger than just the underlying plane bundles being isomorphic.  (This doesn't happen for positive definite metrics, because the inclusion $O(n)\to GL(n)$ is a homotopy equivalence.)  So a bundle with structure group $SO(1,1)$ is trivial _as a Lorentzian plane bundle_ iff the corresponding line bundle $L_+\cong L_-$ is trivial.  It could be trivial as just a vector bundle even if $L_+$ is nontrivial.

Comment: As I mentioned, $w_2$ of the plane bundle will be $w_1(L_+)^2$, and so $w_1(L_+)^2\neq 0$ is a sufficient condition for the plane bundle to be nontrivial (as a vector bundle, not just as a Lorentzian plan bundle); I don't know off the top of my head whether it is necessary.  An example of this is when $L_+$ is the non-orientable line bundle on $\mathbb{RP}^2$.

Comment: To be very concrete in terms of matrices, an element of $O(1,1)$ is a matrix $\begin{pmatrix}a & cb \\ b & ca\end{pmatrix}$ where $a^2-b^2=1$ and $c=\pm 1$.  $SO(1,1)$ is those matrices with $c=1$, and $SO^+(1,1)$ is those where additionally $a>0$.  So $SO^+(1,1)$ is contractible because it is just one branch of the hyperbola $\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2:a^2-b^2=1\}$.

Comment: For completeness, you may want to add a discussion in the case when $\Sigma$ is a surface: In the non-orientable case indeed $w_1^2$ can be nonzero, while if $\Sigma$ is oriented then $w_1^2=0$ for every $w_1\in H^1(\Sigma, Z/2)$ and every oriented Lorentzian plane bundle is trivial as a vector bundle. I suspect that the assumption that $\Sigma$ is an oriented surface is implicit in physics references that OP mentioned.